# InputPane covers Context Flyout UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Virtual keyboard covers MenuFlyout for RichEditBox. There is any way to move to top the flyout? Also tried hide keyboard with `PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus` and `TryHide()`, but there is many bugs. I can provide fully the code, but I think it is not interesting.

Comment: `MenuFlyout` has `Placement` property, please try to set Placement as `Top`.

Comment: no, it not helps :(

Comment: Please check [`ShowAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout.showat) method, you could show your `MenuFlyout` with specific point when your keyboard show.